# Сохранить byte[] с помощью SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#

Впервые работаю с типом Varbinary(Max) в sql server. Храню там различные файлы - word,txt,image. В программе хочу реализовать кнопку, при нажатии на которую пользователь выбирал куда сохранить файл. Возможно ли как-то это сделать с учетом того, что файлы разные (В базе есть string поле для хранения, например, "docx"). Или это надо проверять расширения файла и уже для каждого отдельно метод конвертирования писать. Спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: Храните имя файла с расширением в той же таблице и все дела. И что вы куда конвертировать хотите? Файл - это набор байт, вы храните его в бинарном поле в том виде, в котором он есть.

Comment: @tym32167 Да, я храню поле с расширением в той е таблице. Я просто только что подумал, могу ли я в зависимости от расширения ставить свойству SaveFileDialog DefaultEx и все проблемы будут решены?

Comment: ну если вы в БД добавили ворд документ и сохранили имя ворд документа с расширением ворд документа, то при загрузке из бд ставьте расширение вашего диалога для ворд документа и качайте ворд документ и сохраняйте его как ворд документ, и он будет настоящим ворд документом :)

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо. Поторопился с вопросом. Удалите тему, пожалуйста:D

Comment: @tym32167, не удаляйте тему, напишите ответ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку вы храните имя файла, его расширение и его контент (в байтах), то это все, что требуется, чтобы файл восстановить. Поэтому смело ставьте сохраненное расширение в вашем диалоге сохранения файла и заливайте в выбранный юзером файл байты из БД - файл будет восстановлен. Ничего никуда конвертировать не нужно.